# How to format output into columns?

Tags: linux, perl, scripting, output

How can I modify the following script to that it displays each value in its corresponding colum:
The body of the script looks like this:

```
( $vmdisk, $totalio, $readpercentage, $cachehitpercentage, $currentkbpersecond,
  $maximumkbpersecond, $currentiopersecond, $maximumiopersecond
) = split (",", $line);
$totalio =~ s/\"//g;
$readpercentage =~ s/\"//g;
$cachehitpercentage =~ s/\"//g;
$currentkbpersecond =~ s/\"//g;
$maximumkbpersecond =~ s/\"//g;
$currentiopersecond =~ s/\"//g;
$maximumiopersecond =~ s/\"//g;

print "totalio:$totalio readpercentage:$readpercentage cachehitpercentage:$cachehitpercentage currentkbpersecond:$currentkbpersecond maximumkbpersecond:$maximumkbpersecond currentiopersecond:$currentiopersecond maximumiopersecond:$maximumiopersecond";
```

This will display this type of formatted output:

```
totalio:75.0 readpercentage:20.0 cachehitpercentage:93.3 currentkbpersecond:33.8 maximumkbpersecond:33.8 currentiopersecond:15.0 maximumiopersecond:15.0
```

everything is in one line. My goal is to get the output into columns and make it more readable. For example like this:

```
totalio readpercentage cachehitpercentage

75.00 20.0 93.0
```

How can I do this?

Comment: I'd go, at least if you are panning on doing this report regularly, with Template::Toolkit or HTML::Template and output the report as HTML table.

Comment: yuck! Use Text::CSV_XS to parse your input!

Comment: Your split method seem a little heavy... Could you give us your *input* ? Maybe something like `y|"||d;@array=split(" ")`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Formats would be something to consider especially if you were taking these measurements several times and printing to stdout or a log file.  [perldoc perlform](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlform.html)

```
$line = "0.0,75.0,20.0,93.3,33.8,33.8,15.0,15.0";

( $vmdisk, $totalio, $readpercentage, $cachehitpercentage, $currentkbpersecond, $maximumkbpersecond, $currentiopersecond, $maximumiopersecond) = split (",", $line);

$totalio =~ s/\"//g;
$readpercentage =~ s/\"//g;
$cachehitpercentage =~ s/\"//g;
$currentkbpersecond =~ s/\"//g;
$maximumkbpersecond =~ s/\"//g;
$currentiopersecond =~ s/\"//g;
$maximumiopersecond =~ s/\"//g;

format REPORT_HEADER = 
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Total IO     Read %     Cache Hit %     Current kB/sec     Max kB/sec     Current IO/sec     Max IO/sec
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
.

format REPORT_BODY = 
 @####.#    @###.##         @###.##            @###.##        @###.##            @###.##        @###.##
$totalio, $readpercentage, $cachehitpercentage, $currentkbpersecond, $maximumkbpersecond, $currentiopersecond, $maximumiopersecond
.

select(STDOUT);

$~= "REPORT_HEADER";
write;

$~= "REPORT_BODY";
write;
```

Would give you output like so:

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Total IO     Read %     Cache Hit %     Current kB/sec     Mac kB/sec     Current IO/sec     Max IO/sec
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    75.0      20.00           93.30              33.80          33.80              15.00          15.00
```

Comment: that is awesome! how can I add another column? for example say I want to add the time as the first field $time, $readpercentage, ....

Answer (score 4):

```
    printf "%-10s %-10s %-10s\n", $totalio, $readpercentage, $cachehitpercentage;
```

Should do what you're looking for.  Just append variables according to the pattern as needed.  Reference:  [printf](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/printf.html)

Answer (score 1):

Sorry I'm just walking out the door or I would give a better example. The thing you are looking for are `formats`. Read more at [`perldoc perlform`](http://p3rl.org/perlform).

Comment: I've heard [Perl6::Form](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Perl6::Form) (Perl6-like forms for Perl5) is way better then the builtin forms.

Answer (score 0):

Among the others, there's also the handy dandy [Text::Table](http://search.cpan.org/~shlomif/Text-Table/lib/Text/Table.pm).